# Getting Instagram Business Account media objects via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to use the Instagram Graph API to export the text and media from stories posted by an Instagram business account.

Following the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started), they query the Facebook pages that the logged-in user has admin access to, then query for the associated Instagram business account, then query for that account's media.

However, when I do this (while logged into my Facebook account) in the Graph API Explorer, it doesn't list any pages, even though I am definitely an admin on the Facebook page in question.  (I am listed as having "full control" in the business account.)

Why do I not have access?

Comment: Perhaps you did not _select_ the page, when you granted the app permission to access your pages? Try and remove all granted permissions, and then add them again - it should ask you _which_ pages you want to grant access to then in the login dialog.